# set log severity on google cloud without using google-cloud-logging library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to correctly output logs on my service running on google cloud, and for the most part they are correctly identified (`DEBUG` and `INFO` logs, being sent to `stdout`, are marked as info, whereas `WARNING`, `ERROR`, and `CRITICAL` logs are sent to `stderr` and are marked as error). Now, I am trying to get the exact severity out of them, without needing to use the `google-cloud-logging` library. Is there a way where I can accomplish this?

Here an example of what I currently obtain is shown, with severity (icon on the left) matching whether the log comes from `stdout` or `stderr`.

[image: google cloud logging example]

This is what I'm trying to obtain, but without using the `google-cloud-logging` library

[image: expected log severities]

Edit:

my logs are written to the output streams in json format, by using the `python-json-logger` library for python. My google cloud logs have their information stored as in the picture below. We are not using fluentd for log parsing.

[image: current log parsing structure]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research and help from
@SerhiiRohoza It doesn't seem you can, so in order to set the severity on google cloud you need to add the google-cloud-logging library to your project and set it up as [described on the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python).

Answer (score 3):

I also ran in this issues, where GCP would parse my log levels incorrectly.

Here's a simple trick that worked for me:

```
_GCP_LOGGING_FORMAT = "{levelname:<.1}{asctime}.{msecs}000 {process} {name}:{lineno}] {message}"
_DATE_FMT = "%m%d %H:%M:%S"

logging.basicConfig(format=_GCP_LOGGING_FORMAT, datefmt=_DATE_FMT, style="{")
```

E.g.:

```
D1011 16:28:57.528787 1 <module>:89] Time to process request: 1234
```

If you are using loguru, it's equivalent will be:

```
    _GCP_LOG_FORMAT = (
        "{level:<.1}{time:MMDD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS} {process} {name}:{line}] {message} | {extra}"
    )

    logger.remove()
    logger.add(
        sys.stdout,
        format=_GCP_LOG_FORMAT,
        level=log_level,
        colorize=True,
    )
```

Comment: How did you find this format? I'm looking through GCP documentation and can't find any reference to this. All the docs seem to push towards using structuring logging via a client library or by outputting json blobs.

Comment: I was able to verify this format works. Here's a version that I think is a bit better, because it includes just the milliseconds (3 digits) without extra 0s, and uses the filename (`{name}` is the name of the root logger):

`logging.basicConfig(format="{levelname:<.1}{asctime}.{msecs:03.0f} {process} {filename}:{lineno}] {message}", datefmt="%m%d %H:%M:%S", style="{")`


example:

`W1027 15:58:20.394 73495 my_module.py:48] my message`

Comment: I found this format here, https://github.com/benley/python-glog/blob/master/glog.py#L40